# react am I mutating my state in case it is not an object or array?

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I know how To avoid mutating objects and arrays in react state, but I am not sure about variables that are not objects and arrays like this example

```
 this.state = {
        cubeNumber: 0,
    }

onNumberChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
}

cubeArrayRender = () => {
    let { cubeNumber } = this.state;
```

am I mutating state by using parseInt like this?

```
    let cubes = parseInt(cubeNumber, 10);
```

or if I write like this?

```
let cubes = cubeNumber;
cubes = 2;
```

If I am mutating state, how can I avoid it?

Comment: No, you are not mutating the state. If you wrote `this.state.cubeNumber = 2;` you would be mutating the state object.

Answer (score 2):

According to React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) you shouldn't assign state like this

`// Wrong
this.state.comment = 'Hello';`

But only this:

`// Correct
this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});`

So yeah you are not mutating state in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can mutate state only acting directly on this.state or through setState.

Answer (score 1):

You are not mutating state (or anything) by using the method you have shown in your example. `parseInt` returns an Integer and does not modify the String/Number that you give it, instead creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Steve Vaughan answer. In this case you are not mutating state because the state 
you used for this test is value type. But object are reference type. While you assigning
the `cubeNumber` to new variable `cube` that makes the deep copy. But that's not same for objects, you are just passing reference.

For example:

```
//intial state
this.state = {
    user: {name:"sarath"},
    age:25
}

let age=this.state.age; //deep copy
age=35; // this not going affect the original state

let user=this.state.user //Shallow copy 
user.name="kumar" //It mutates the original object also
```

**output:**
    original age: 25 
   new age: 35 
   name: Kumar
   new name: Kumar

you can avoid the mutation by using two methods

- **Object Assign**

  This method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.

  `let user= Object.Assign({},this.state.user); //deep copy of values
  user.name="kumar"; // Here the original state is untouched.`
- **Deep cloning of entire object**

  `Object.Assign` copies property values only. It won't copy the reference inside of the Object.

For example:

```
//intial state
this.state = {
    user: {name:"sarath",interest:{music:"western",sports:"foot ball"},
    age:25
}

let user=Object.Assign({},this.state.user);
user.name="Jasrin"; 
user.interest.sports="cricket";

console.log(this.state.user.name); //sarath
console.log(user.name); //kumar
console.log(this.state.user.interest.sports); //cricket
console.log(this.state.user.interest.sports); //cricket
```

Alternate way to do deep cloning is

```
let user=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.user))
```